# Html to Markdown

Tags: html, powershell, markdown

How to convert HTML to Markdown using powershell?
Is there any possibility to convert it without using ugly constructions as:

```
    $content = $content -replace "<em>", "*"
    $content = $content -replace "</em>", "*"
    $content = $content -replace "<b>", "**"
    $content = $content -replace "</b>", "**"
    $content = $content -replace "<strong>", "**"
    $content = $content -replace "</strong>", "**"
    $content = $content -replace "&quot;", "'"
    $content = $content -replace '<i>'
    $content = $content -replace '</i>'
```

Comment: Please show an example of what you have and what you want to end up with.